# Error occurred on routing_api __get _route response status code 403

Tags: python-3.x, api, routes, herepy

I'd like to compute the travel time between two points. So I use the RoutingApi from herepy library (as reported in the example at https://github.com/abdullahselek/HerePy/blob/master/examples/routing_api.py):

```
    from herepy import (
    RoutingApi,
    RouteMode,
    MatrixRoutingType,
    MatrixSummaryAttribute,
    RoutingTransportMode,
    RoutingMode,
    RoutingApiReturnField,
    RoutingMetric,
    RoutingApiSpanField,
    AvoidArea,
    AvoidFeature,
    Avoid,
    Truck,
    ShippedHazardousGood,
    TunnelCategory,
    TruckType,
)
routing_api = RoutingApi(api_key="my_key")
response = routing_api.truck_route(
    waypoint_a=[lat_a, lon_a],
    waypoint_b=[lat_b, lon_b],
    modes=[RouteMode.truck, RouteMode.fastest],
)
print(response.as_dict())
```

Though, even if my api key is valid and "enabled" on the HERE developer platform, I get the following error message:

```
HEREError: Error occurred on routing_api __get _route response status code 403
```

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening and how to solve that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with coordinates.
Looking at the example at https://github.com/abdullahselek/HerePy/blob/master/examples/routing_api.py

if you try:

```
response = routing.car_route(waypoint_a=[41.9798, -87.8801], waypoint_b=[41.9043, -87.9216], modes=[herepy.RouteMode.car, herepy.RouteMode.fastest])
print(response.as_dict())
```

it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).